# Passing content outside of an asynchronous server socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm not even sure how this would work because at its very nature an asynchronous server socket can accept multiple connections.

What I would like to do is capture content if it meets a certain format and pass it outside the server socket so that other classes can reference it. I followed the MSDN code for building a Asynchronous Server Socket. Here is the callback that reads the content.

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    string content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socketH:\JCI\BWSI\Integrations\Middleware\Jci\Jci\Framework.Jci.EventEngine\EventEngineRTLSEvents.cs
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There might be more data, so store the data recieved so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf('\u001c') > -1)
        {
            // ALl the data has been read from the
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}", content.Length, content);
            // Echo the data back to the client.
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data recieived. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working as you expected in the code you posted? Then what would you expect. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is that you are trying to achieve, what your approach is and where you got stuck. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't really understand your question, and I haven't tried to read your code. But I'll comment on one thing. You say, "at it's very nature an asynchronous server socket can accept multiple connections". I have a feeling that you don't understand what this means. You can program a Socket to Listen for a connection and then Accept the connection. But that spawns another Socket that represents that connection. The Socket used for Listen / Accept can then listen for and accept another connection, which again spawns another Socket. Each connection is on a different Socket; content is not mixed.

Comment: @RenniePet thats not what i'm saying the fact that a new socket is spawned for each connection is another problem I will have to deal with. But right now my problem is that the content is spawned in a void method and if I change that method so that i can pass content out it breaks the whole chain of code. My question as stated is to grab the content of a connection and pass it outside the server socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the basic issue is this: when some data is received on the socket, that results in some new object being created in your program, and you want some code to operate on this object to process it in some way.

So, let's think about it this way: when you want some code to execute, how do you make that happen? Since in C# all code exists in methods, you need to call a method to make the code execute.

Now, in the scenario of an asynchronously handled socket, you have some options. Code always executes in the context of a thread, so you need to think about which thread you want to execute this particular code. That really amounts to there being just two options: **1)** execute in the current thread, or **2)** execute in a different thread.

Okay, now we're getting somewhere. If we pick option #1, how does that happen? Easy...just call the method from your `ReadCallback()` method. If you've created an object you want that called method to process, just pass that object to the method when you call it.

And it really is that simple **(*)**.

Now, what if you want to pick #2? Well…that's a bit more complicated. First, you need to find a thread to execute the code, and second you need to get the data to that thread.

I can think of at least three obvious ways to go about this:

1. Use an existing UI thread. In this case, you'll use e.g. the `Control.Invoke()` method or `Dispatcher.Invoke()` (for Winforms or WPF, respectively). A similar mechanism is available in ASP.NET.
2. Use the thread pool, e.g. via the Task Parallel Library. For example, you might use the `Task.Run()` method to start a new task.
3. Use a producer/consumer implementation, in which you've previously started a thread dedicated just to consuming the data objects created when receiving data. For example, you could start a new thread with a method that just uses `foreach` to pull items from a `BlockingCollection<T>` instance, while the `ReadCallback()` method adds items to that same instance.

In the first two options above, data moves to the other thread via an argument to the method being invoked, or as a captured variable in an anonymous method being invoked (I find the latter more convenient than the former, but either works fine). In the third option, obviously the data moves from the socket's thread to the consuming thread via the shared collection.

I hope that the above is enough to get you pointed in the right direction. As asked, the question is fairly broad (possibly too broad), but I think what I've written here is still reasonably concise, with just enough vagueness to remain applicable to whatever your scenario is, without being so vague as to be non-useful. :)

**(*)** Actually, it's a little more complicated than that, in that you have a number of mechanisms by which you can call a method. The simplest is that the method name is hard-coded into your `ReadCallback()` method; you just call the one method you know you always want to call. But that limits reusability of the code, and couples it to unrelated code which makes it harder to maintain.

Other options include:

1. Declaring an event on your socket client object where the `ReadCallback()` method exists, and have the object that's supposed to actually process the data subscribe to that event. The `ReadCallback()` method would raise the event, passing the object to process as part of the event's arguments.
2. Simply passing a callback delegate to the socket client object, very much in the same way you currently pass a delegate representing your `ReadCallback()` method to the socket class.

Comment: Good work - you've written more than me, and covered more possibilities, and beat me to it!  :-)

Comment: @Peter DunihoI I thought about calling a method to pass the content to a public string  but my concern is that if multiple clients pass multiple content strings then the public content string will be overwritten. I thought maybe i could create a function that creates a object and is called by the readcall function but even then i could create a problem with the method being overwritten.

Comment: @Phil: you do need to provide a mechanism by which you keep data for each client separate. This depends on the exact design of your overall program, which you haven't shared with us. But typically, it involves some object that represents the client (created when the client connection is accepted), and which receives the results of receiving data from the socket. In that way, each client has its own context and won't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is not really intended to be an answer, but I find that writing a lot of text as comments is problematic.

I've now actually taken a look at your code, and maybe I'm beginning to understand what you're asking. Your use of the phrase "pass it outside the server socket" is partly what confused me - what you mean is "give the data to a method that is not a dedicated part of the Socket processing code", right?

The simple way to do this is, once you've accumulated a complete "logical message" is to call a method to process it from your asynchronous ReadCallback method. So the business logic is actually running as a subroutine of the Socket code. But this is only OK for trivial processing that does not block for any length of time.

A more common technique is to use multi-threading and cross-thread dispatching techniques. Then the business logic is semi-independent of the Socket code. There are many possible ways of doing this. I've written code that explicitly uses an AutoResetEvent and a queue of messages (with a lock), but it is a bit messy. The modern way (which I've not used personally) is via the C# async and await facility.

Finally, a few comments on the code you present. It is safer to not use an end-of-file token, and instead prefix each logical message with a message length, for example an Int32 encoded/decoded via BitConverter to a 4-byte array (be careful of big endian vs. little endian). The problem with the end-of-file marker is that it is conceivable that the marker could be split between two calls to your ReadCallback method.

Similarly, it is best to first accumulate the entire message as raw bytes, and then decode the whole message back to string. Again, the problem could be that a UTF-8 two-byte sequence could get split across two calls to ReadCallback.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Just want to mention that the fact that TCP/IP input is considered to be a stream of bytes does make the processing tricky. I've already indicated that a length prefix is safer than an end-of-file token, and that accumulating the whole message before converting from UTF-8 to string is safer than converting individual segments.

But in addition you have to be careful that you have at least 4 bytes before you try to convert it into the length. It is conceivable that you get one message plus the first 2 bytes of the next one, so you only have half of the length prefix for the second message. Then you have to just save those 2 bytes and wait for the next call before you can even convert the length.

Normally you get a whole message on each call, and it is very rare that this streaming causes problems. And it never happens during testing. But according to Murphy's law eventually it will happen, and at the worst possible time.

Comment: _"this is not really intended to be an answer, but I find that writing a lot of text as comments is problematic"_ -- FWIW: if you have a non-answer that seems too voluminous for a comment, then you should invite the OP to a chat session. Answers really should actually be answers. (That said, I've seen worse "answers" than yours here, and who knows...maybe the OP will in fact find it useful as an "answer").